# re.findall how to return matches with repeated ones

Tags: python, findall

I have list of IP:PORT in html and when i use findall to search all ip i get the list of all ip becouse IP are unique , some of ports are the same and i get by example list of 100 IP's and only 87 ports. How to find all ports with the repeated ones ?

```
proxies = re.findall("[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}",html)

ports = re.findall("[0-9]{1,3}\,[0-9]{1,3}\,[0-9]{1,3}\,[0-9]{1,3}",html)
#ports are coded to looks like this 47,46,47,46

print len(proxies)
print len(ports)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to find the matches and trimming the non-unique results?

Comment: Can you provide some of the sample data?  It's entirely possible you can get both sets at once, but seeing the input would make that determination a ton easier.

Comment: But why not to find all strings with combinations IP:Port and then simply split the results the way you need?

Comment: To clarify list of ip:port looks like on this site http://proxyhttp.net/ , there is not exacly ip:port format ..

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the source file, I can only make some basic points.

- Port numbers are not limited to 3 digits, so you are excluding any port over 999
- Do the port numbers only show up as a list of 4 ports? You said the format was a list of `IP:PORT`, but that is not what you are checking for.

**EDIT:**

Look at the source of the page more carefully. There are entries that do not have 4 port numbers.

```
<tr>
    <td class="t_ip">151.9.233.6</td>
    <td class="t_port">50,42</td>
    <td class="t_country"><img src="/images/flags/it.png" alt="it" />Italy</td>
    <td class="t_anonymity">

            High

    </td>
    <td class="t_https">-</td>
    <td class="t_checked">00:02:16</td>
    <td class="t_check">
        <a href="" class="a_check" >check</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

It also seems like it would be a lot easier to check for `class="t_ip"` and `class="t_port"` and grab the contents of that element.

```
<td class="t_ip">(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})</td>
<td class="t_port">((\d,?)+)</td>
```

**Note:** The IP address expression will match invalid IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will help you too much, but just another option:

```
txt = """
<tr>
    <td class="t_ip">151.9.233.6</td>
    <td class="t_port">50,42</td>
    <td class="t_country"><img src="/images/flags/it.png" alt="it" />Italy</td>
    <td class="t_anonymity">

            High

    </td>
    <td class="t_https">-</td>
    <td class="t_checked">00:02:16</td>
    <td class="t_check">
        <a href="" class="a_check" >check</a>
    </td>
</tr>    
"""

txt = [line.strip() for line in txt.split('\n')]

#clstaglen = len('</td>') => 5
getVals = lambda startTxt: [line[len(startTxt):len(line)-5] for line in txt if line.startswith(startTxt)]

print getVals('<td class="t_ip">')
print getVals('<td class="t_port">')
```